# How does implicit conversion work in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given the following type definition:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

I can declare a function that returns a Set two ways

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = 
  value => value == elem
```

or

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set =
  Set(elem)
```

The second definition uses the Set from the Scala Standard Library rather than the declared type, but how does Scala implicitly convert to the declared type Set? The implicit conversion seems odd to me.

To clarify the second definition, I've changed the name of the type in the following valid code:

```
type SetX = Int => Boolean

def singletonSet(elem: Int): SetX =
    Set(elem)
```

Answer (score 7):

[`Set[A]` extends `A => Boolean`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/Set.scala#L24), so there's no implicit conversion in place, just subtyping.

Answer (score 0):

Set has a apply function A => Boolean, that for every A it return true if it exist in the Set or false if it doesn't (it call the 'contains' function). so for example:

```
val sx = Set(1,2,3)
sx(1) // true
sx(5) // false
```

in the singletonSet you create a Set[Int] with one element and return the "apply" function.
So actually, the singletonSet may be defined as:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int) = Set(elem).contains _
```